# Get value from constructor to a function in php class

Tags: php, class

i have a class like:

```
class List_PendingVerify extends Rs_List {

 public function __construct( $id ) {
           }

    protected function loadData( ) {
           }
}
```

Now i how could i get value of $id in loadData function ?

so that i can be able to echo $id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class List_PendingVerify extends Rs_List {
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    protected function loadData() {
        echo $this->id;
    }
}
```

I recommend reading the [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) documentation. (In particular, the [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) section is relevant here.)